# Is it possible to call a php script from another?

Tags: php

I'm very new to php but I've had some experience with c# java and vb. I wrote a simple contact form form my website and it will send me an email as well as send the user a confirmation email. This works just fine. Now I would like to add the person's name and email address to a database for future mailings. If I were to do this in java or c# these two activities would be split into 2 or possibly more classes for use in other situations where you might need to email or add to a database. Is this possible in php or should I just write it all in one file?

thanks!
(edit) here's some code that I wrote:

```
<?php

                    $to = "craigsmith866@gmail.com";
                    $subject = "New Contact";
                    $message = "A new contact named : " .  $_POST["fname"] . " " . $_POST["lname"] . "\n" . "has written you a message:" . "\n" . "\n" . $_POST["comment"];
                    $from = ($_POST["email"]);
                    mail($to,$subject,$message,"From" . " " . $_POST["email"]);
                    echo "<p> Thank you for your time helping me to build a better website!</p> <br/> <p> You will recieve an email confirmation shortly </p> <br/> <p> You will be redirected in 5 seconds</p>" ;
                    $return_message = "Thank you for your comments and suggestions. \n If you required further assistance I will be with you shortly. \n \n Yours, \n  \n Craig A. Smith  \n  \n Original Message: \n" . $_POST["comment"];
                    mail($from,"Thank You!",$return_message);
                ?>
```

this is the script that is ran after the user clicks submit. (there is also some validation in the head to make sure all fields were filled in)

how do I send the info from the contact form to the next script that will add to the database? I could very easily just write it all in one script but this site is my first to use php and is my home page that I will advertise on my resume. I'm currently looking for work as I just got out of school.

Comment: If you think you might need it again, it is definitely a good idea to put it in different classes, check http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php although you can also include your files manually: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php.

Comment: There's not really any need to write a class for that. You should use a database class, but the adding of that contact can be in a simple function.

Comment: try http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/object-oriented-php-for-beginners/

Comment: The best practices you're used to in C# or Java will almost all apply here in php land, as a general rule.  You're on the right track, getting the basics down in straight PHP, but you'll want to look into frameworks at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write all in one or split to files, in big projects for good project structure it is better to split into files, this method is procedural programming, you can also and should write  using Classes as you mention or even use an MVC framework such as **[CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter)** (simple to learn and awesome documentation very powerful) but there are many more.

**EDIT:**

If you want to make it extremely dead simple and procedural (assuming you set up a database with mysql and cleared nasty **[XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)**):

```
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("database");
$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (`id`, `fname`, `email`) VALUES ('', '".mysql_real_esacpe_string($_POST["fname"])."', '".mysql_real_esacpe_string($_GET["email"])."')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: since you've posted as an actual answer do you want to give some example code?

Comment: I set up a linux web server with php and mysql for testing at home. I don't know what you mean about "cleared nasty XSS" but I was able to connect to the database, add, delete and update contacts with php. Your code would be in a different file or in the same script? That's where I'm getting stuck. Defiantly I could use something like add_contact() new_contact = add_contact($_POST["fname"], $_Post["email"]);

Comment: You can put the code above or below mail, in a separate file or the same file it does not matter in this situation, and yes you can make a class to add a contact but you should first learn php basics and syntex

Comment: @Eldar The basics is what I'm looking for here. The syntex to call another class/file/script.

Comment: L0L, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php use it `include_once("my_db_action_file.php");`, there are 4 functions but very similar: require, require_once, include, include_once, if require will not find the file it will output fatal error and stop script, include will output a warning, and the "once" says the file will be only included once time this run no matter how many times you try to require or include it afterwards.

Comment: @Eldar how do you pass variables from one file to another? I want to send fname, lname, and email to my_db_action_file

Comment: $_POST array is available on all places its a global.